# How to copy a .sh file to 'bin/sh/'

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to copy a .sh file into 'bin/sh' directory, but I am not able to access 'sh'. Is there any way or command to copy .sh file to 'sh' directory?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is not a directory...why do you think you need to copy anything there?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is the Bourne shell and you should not pass any sh scripts there.

Comment: Ok, I am new to Linux and that was a understanding mistek. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @Himanshu What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you make your own sh script and want it to be found and executed from your shell prompt you:

- Change rights for the script file myscript.sh

  chmod +w myscript.sh

or

```
chmod 755 myscript
```

etc.. depending on who is allowed to execute and change the script.

- You can copy the file to /bin/ (not recommended) or /usr/bin (not as bad, and the place to put it possibly if you have more users than yourself on the system) or you add a new path where you keep your sh scripts into the PATH environment. If you run bash it is in ~/.bashrc.

You can test this from the prompt before changing  .bashrc if you (example in bash) do

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/myscripts/
```

For scripts you have put in your own directory myscripts.
To put it into /usr/bin you do

```
sudo cp myscript.sh /usr/bin/.
```

If you do not have any sudo rights, you are bound to the latter solution with a directory of your own where you put your sh files and changing the PATH.

- Recommended to study: read up on the man pages for chmod and bash. Also on changing environment variables.

Comment: you are a kind and generous soul. +1